# iOS : Working wth mkv or mka containers

Tags: iphone, ios, matroska

This may sound a newbie question, anyway I'm new to iOS dev.

Is it possible to extract mkv (matroska video) or mka (matroska audio) files, are the those containers supported by iOS at all ?

After googling for some time couldn't find anything valuable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not supported by the iOS SDK.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html for Video Technologies supported

Comment: but in appstore there are lots of apps like this one http://itunes.apple.com/am/app/playable-play-almost-anything/id502405034?mt=8 that claim the support for mkv, they might be using 3rd party codec. Is it generally accepted by apple to use third party media playing libraries ? And also if mkv is not supported by iOS how user can transfer those files to iDevice using itunes ?

Comment: You have to use a third party library. If you use a third party library, you are bound by those license terms which may mean that you have to give away all of your source code for your app. Just because a file format isn't supported doesn't mean you can't transfer it onto your device - it just means the SDK won't be able to play it.

Comment: Thanks Nick, my last question can you please provide the link to the those license terms ?

Comment: It depends on the library that you use!